# Is the Riemann zeta function irrational for all integers $n\geq 2$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

The Riemann zeta function for any integer $n\geq 2$ is defined as

$\zeta(n) = \dfrac{2^n}{2^n -1}\prod_{p\geq 3} \dfrac{p^n}{p^n -1} $

Observe that $\zeta(n)$ can only be rational if there is sufficient cancellation of prime factors in the above representation. For all $p \geq 3$, note that $2 \mid p^n - 1$. Hence if $\zeta(n)$ is rational, notice that the denominator would be divisible by an infinitely large exponent of 2, which is impossible ?

Comment: The argument is wrong. The fact that a sequence is rational does not mean that its limit is rational.

Comment: Well, $$\frac{1}{2}\prod_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{2^{2^k}+1}{2^{2^k}} = \dfrac{2^{2^n}-1}{2^{2^n}} \to 1,$$ so that argument doesn't quite work.

Comment: @almagest The OP's argument is completely wrong, but if you think about it, your second sentence does very little to support this claim :).

Comment: @ErickWong Well his argument only makes any kind of sense if he assumes that the factors in the members of the sequence are somehow preserved (unless cancelled) in the limit. So I was attacking what I saw as his premise.

Comment: @almagest The false belief in the OP's mind is rather that some limit of rational numbers $p_n/q_n$ is not rational when $p_n\to\infty$ and $q_n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did Well, that's a conclusion of the OP's belief.  My guess for the underlying premise would be "if a sequence of rationals converges to a rational number then it must also converge $p$-adically".  The mental model blatantly implodes when taken globally, but the false belief might be sustained at a handful of places $p$ :).

Comment: @ErickWong Isn't the false implication in your comment the contrapositive of the equally false implication in mine?

Comment: @Did Hmmm, I think I messed up my phrasing.  The implicit notion I'm attributing to OP isn't really "$q_n$ converges $p$-adically".  It's more like "$v_p(q_n)$ is eventually constant", which is neither stronger nor weaker than convergence.  It is possible for $q_n \to \infty$ even though $v_p(q_n)$ is eventually constant for all $p$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question in the title is widely conjectured to be "yes", but it has yet to be proven and your argument has a fundamental flaw.  It is known to be true when $n$ is even (transcendentality of $\pi$), when $n=3$ (Apery's theorem), and for infinitely many other odd values of $n$ that we only have partial results on.  For instance Zudilin proved that at least one of $\zeta(5), \zeta(7), \zeta(9), \zeta(11)$ is irrational without concretely establishing that any particular value is irrational.

The example of Daniel Fischer in the comments demonstrates the flaw in your argument: you are making the assumption that the power of $2$ dividing the rational *limit* of a sequence of rationals can be computed from the powers of $2$ dividing individual terms.  But his example shows that those two quantities are completely unrelated; the left-hand side has "infinitely" many powers of $2$ in the denominator, but the limit has absolutely none.